# Why does this variable have an instantiatedness of free?

Tags: types, mercury

I've written a Mercury function to calculate the length of a list skeleton, but it doesn't compile and I don't understand why. I'd like to know what's going on here. (In the code below, the `inst`, `func`, and `mode` statements are from the Mercury Reference Manual, sections [4.1](http://mercurylang.org/information/doc-latest/mercury_ref/Insts-modes-and-mode-definitions.html#Insts-modes-and-mode-definitions) and [4.2](http://mercurylang.org/information/doc-latest/mercury_ref/Predicate-and-function-mode-declarations.html#Predicate-and-function-mode-declarations). I'm writing a function body from the manual's declarations.)

```
:- inst my_listskel == bound( [] ; [free | my_listskel] ).

:- func my_length(list(T)) = int.
:- mode my_length(in(my_listskel)) = out.

my_length([]) = 0.
my_length([_ | Tl]) = Length :-
    TailLength = my_length(Tl),
    Length = 1 + TailLength.
```

That code gives me the following compiler error, where line 26 is `TailLength = my_length(Tl)`:

```
mode_test.m:026: In clause for `my_length(in((mode_test.my_listskel))) = out':
mode_test.m:026:   in argument 1 of call to function `mode_test.my_length'/1:
mode_test.m:026:   mode error: variable `Tl' has instantiatedness `free',
mode_test.m:026:   expected instantiatedness was `bound((list.[]) ;
mode_test.m:026:   list.'[|]'(free, ...))'.
```

How does `Tl` get an instantiatedness of free? My understanding is that `Tl` can either be an instance of `my_listskel` or the empty list, and that both of those would be bound, not free.

Is my problem here that I'm dealing with a partially-instantiated data structure (which isn't yet supported)? I suspect this might be the case. But the example is from the reference manual, which suggests that this ought to be supported.

Comment: I've reproduced this issue.  You're probably right that this is because partially instantiated data structures aren't supported by the implementation, even though they're legal in the language.  The language is separate from the implementation.  Nevertheless I'll ask the other developers and attempt to get a clearer answer.  Thanks.