# Mercury List Unification

Tags: mercury

I'm trying to learn [Mercury](https://www.mercurylang.org).  I've been messing around with lists, but I can't get a seemingly-simple unification to work.  Here's my reduced example case:

```
main(!IO) :-
  [X,Y] = List,
  List = [1,2], % Error
  io.write(List, !IO),
  io.nl(!IO).
```

On the line `List = [1,2]` I get the following error (formatted and slightly edited):

```
main.m:024: In clause for `main(di, uo)':
mode error in unification of `List' and `list.[V_11 | V_21]'.
Variable `List' has instantiatedness
`unique(list.'[|]'(free, unique(list.'[|]'(free, unique((list.[]))))))', 
term `list.[V_11 | V_21]' has instantiatedness
`list.'[|]'( unique(1), free )'.
```

That doesn't seem right, though; specifically the instantiatedness of `[1,2]`.  It's a literal; shouldn't its instantiatedness be, like, `list.'[|]'( unique(1), list.'[|]'( unique(2), [] ) )`?

Is this related somehow to the same partial-instantiation problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684020/why-does-this-variable-have-an-instantiatedness-of-free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a mode-correct program Mercury will re-order goals within a conjunction to try to make a mode-correct program, but before it does this it'll also break complex unfications up into parts.  It looks like Mercury is struggling to re-order the parts of these two unifications to make a mode correct program, even though (from my looking) it should be possible.   Try re-ordering the first two goals.

Comment: Yes, reordering the two lines fixes it.  That doesn't actually solve my problem, though, because this was just a simplification of a more complicated use case; I want to be able to declare an unknown list and later unify values in it.  In the meantime, I tried it out in Prolog, and while the syntax is annoying sometimes, it's mostly doing what I wanted.  It'd be really neat if Mercury could do it, too.

Comment: Side note: if I leave the two lines as given in the question, but write `X` and `Y` instead of `List`, I get the following error, instead: main.m:059: In `__Unify__'((unique((list.[])) >> bound((list.[]))), (bound((list.[])) >> bound((list.[])))): error: implicit determinism declaration not satisfied. Declared `det', inferred `semidet'. Unification of `CastY' and `CastX' can fail.

Comment: @Erhannis: "declare an unknown list and later unify values in it": no that does still not work in Mercury. (See [Q1 here](http://mercurylang.org/information/doc-release/mercury_faq/Unimplemented.html#Unimplemented).)

Comment: @TomasBy Ah, bummer.  Do you know if the related feature is being developed, or where I'd go to ask?

Comment: @Erhannis: I strongly doubt it is being worked on. You can ask on the [mailing list](http://mercurylang.org/contact.html).